# How to pass GCM token from one application to another application in android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Please suggest me solution for above question.
Means send the GCM token from one application to another but first application is installed into the sysyem,but want GCM token into second application in android.

```
mRegistrationProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.registrationProgressBar);
mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mRegistrationProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences
                .getBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
        if (sentToken) {
            mInformationTextView.setText(getString(R.string.gcm_send_message));
        } else {
            mInformationTextView.setText(getString(R.string.token_error_message));
        }
    }
};
mInformationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.informationTextView);

// Registering BroadcastReceiver
registerReceiver();

if (checkPlayServices()) {
    // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Comment: Why do you the gcm token to be shared between two applications? GCM token is supposed to be unique for every application?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you the gcm token to be shared between two applications? GCM token is supposed to be unique for every application?

If you still want send data from one app to another app use intent-filer in actvities.

```
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

            final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(
                    "you.package.name",
                    "you.package.name.class");

            intent.setComponent(cn);
            intent.putExtra("token",token_value);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            startActivity(intent);
```